# Set Background Image for Picker

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to set a Background image like this.

This the background of my picker:

[image]

I tried to use this code:

```
<Grid >
<Image Source="input_mobile_code_brown.png" x:Name="img"></Image>
<Picker></Picker>
</Grid>
```

But it shows the picker first after that the image like stack layout orientation horizontal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[RelativeLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/)** to locate your controls. I write an example for you, you can edit the RelativeLayout to adapt your scenario.

```
    <RelativeLayout Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <Image Source="pickerbackgroundimage.png" Aspect="AspectFit"  x:Name="img"
                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint =
                        "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                             Property=Width,
                             Factor=0,
                             Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint =
                        "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                             Property=Height,
                             Factor=0,
                             Constant=0}"
               />


        <Picker BackgroundColor="Transparent" x:Name="picker" 
                    RelativeLayout.XConstraint =
                        "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                             Property=Width,
                             Factor=0,
                             Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint =
                        "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                             Property=Height,
                             Factor=0,
                             Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint =
                        "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                             ElementName=img,
                             Property=Width,
                             Factor=1,
                             Constant=0}"
                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint =
                        "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                             ElementName=img,
                             Property=Height,
                             Factor=1,
                             Constant=0}"
                />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

It works like this on iOS and Android:
[image]